# What is name of anti pattern !string.IsnullOrEmpty(Employee.Name), (Decapsulation ?)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, code-standards

Very often I run into code that logic that should be within business object is repeated everywhere as such:

```
if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( Employee.Name ) ) Display( Employee.Name );
```

where as it should be like this :

```
if ( Employee.IsNameSpecified ) Display( Employee.Name );
```

and the `Employee.IsNameSpecified` has the logic of value being specified.

This is just one example, many others come to mind that are reverse of OOP , procedural code being used to make logical decisions about business objects.

When Logic is encapsulated in the BusinessObject then it is just normal OOP practice (or doeas that have a different name? ), what is the opposite called ? Decapsulation ?

Comment: I've never heard of a name for it. I just say that it "violates encapsulation" or that it "violates separation of concerns".

Comment: You could just call it "spaghetti code" or "copypasta".

Comment: @4castle : copypasta is new! Never heard that before, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that as one flavor of [TDA](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) (tell, don't ask).

What you are doing here: the client code retrieves a "property" owned by another class to then make a decision based on that value.

TDA implies exactly what your question is about: that *other* class should make that decision for you - your  client code should not know the rules to make that decision.

But please note the "recursion" here: the proposed "solution" still violates TDA. You are *still* fetching a value from another class, so that the client code can make a decision on it.

The only difference: in the first case, you fetch a string, and the client checks if that string is null/empty; in the second case, you fetch a boolean that tells you what to do.

So, the "ideal" OO solution would be more like:

```
employee.display();
```

and the employee doing the correct thing completely on its own. But sure, this implementation can quickly turn into a violation of SRP for example - should an Employee class really know about "displaying" itself?!

Comment: should display be in ViewModel for that business object? the rule of what is considered to be a valod display value can be centralised,

Comment: I guess that really depends on the actual context. If your business object has a View model, then probably yes. I think that additional question really depends on your overall design and model.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not an anti-pattern (and violates the MVC pattern) :

1. Your Employee class is part of your Model.
2. Your if must be in a View class. And this is the role of the View class to display (an) element(s) of the Model layer.
3. Your method is IsNameSpecified is used here to determine if the Name of your Employee have to be displayed.

1+2+3 : your method has to be implemented in your view class. **Not in the model**.

So following your logic (and the ones from other developers writing !string.IsNullOrEmpty), this method is now in the View class : *IsNameSpecific(Employee e)*. And its implementation will only contain one instruction. People will clearly choose to not write this kind of method.

@GhostCat : employee.display(); is clearly a **mistake**... Imagine the case where, for a specific customer of this application, an employee is just a number. And for an other customer, it is a Name and a Role... And so on...

The role of your Model is to only structure information. Not to display itself.

Comment: i really like "The role of your Model is to only structure information. Not to display itself" very insightful, thank you